# How can I simplify the query without using UNION ALL?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT i.id invn_id, IF(ss.serial_id IS NOT NULL, ss.serial_id, NULL) serial_number,
        IF(ss.serial_id IS NOT NULL, 1.000000, -(i.qty)) qty,
        'auto' flag, i.sid site_id, i.prod_id, i.fifo_total_amount, i.trans_date
 FROM inventories i
 INNER JOIN prod p ON p.id = i.prod_id
 LEFT JOIN sale_products sp ON sp.inventory_id = i.id
 LEFT JOIN sale_serial ss ON ss.prod_id = i.prod_id AND ss.sale_id = sp.sale_id
 WHERE i.qty < 0 
        AND ('2015-03-25 00:00:00' IS NULL OR i.trans_date >= '2015-03-25 00:00:00') 
        AND ('2015-03-27 08:27:36' IS NULL OR i.trans_date <= '2015-03-27 08:27:36') 
        AND p.name NOT IN ('Starting Balance' , 'Opening Balance', 'Equity')
        AND i.prod_id = 7655 AND (0 = 0 OR i.sid = 0)
 UNION ALL 
 (
 SELECT i.id invn_id, 
        IF(ss.serial_id IS NOT NULL,ss.serial_id, NULL) serial_number, 
         -(SUM(IF(ss.serial_id IS NOT NULL, 1.000000, -(i.qty))) - -(i.qty)) qty, -- difference
        'auto' flag, i.sid site_id, i.prod_id, i.fifo_total_amount, i.trans_date
 FROM inventories i
 INNER JOIN prod p ON p.id = i.prod_id
 LEFT JOIN sale_products sp ON sp.inventory_id = i.id
 LEFT JOIN sale_serial ss ON ss.prod_id = i.prod_id AND ss.sale_id = sp.sale_id
 WHERE i.qty < 0
        AND ('2015-03-25 00:00:00' IS NULL OR i.trans_date >= '2015-03-25 00:00:00')
        AND ('2015-03-27 08:27:36' IS NULL OR i.trans_date <= '2015-03-27 08:27:36')
        AND p.name NOT IN ('Starting Balance' , 'Opening Balance', 'Equity')
        AND i.prod_id = 7655 AND (0 = 0 OR i.sid = 0)
 GROUP BY i.id -- difference
 HAVING qty > 0 -- difference
 ) 
 ORDER BY site_id , prod_id , trans_date , qty ASC
```

Observe that the second statement (union table) is almost the same as the first statement except for the lines in comment. I'm satisfied with the outcome, but not satisfied with the query because of its redundancy. Is there a possibility to make this brief?

The output I wanna get is something like this, for instance:

I have a total quantity of 5 with an ID of 95514:

```
 +-------+-----------+---------+
 | id    | qty       | prod_id |
 +-------+-----------+---------+
 | 95514 | 5.000000  |    7655 |
 +-------+-----------+---------+
```

If I'll execute the query above, the result will be like this:

```
+---------+---------------+----------+------+---------+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
| invn_id | serial_number | qty      | flag | site_id | prod_id | fifo_total_amount | trans_date          |
+---------+---------------+----------+------+---------+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
|   95514 | 237658        | 1.000000 | auto |       1 |    7655 |         2763.0194 | 2010-07-22 09:48:24 |
|   95514 | 237671        | 1.000000 | auto |       1 |    7655 |         2763.0194 | 2010-07-22 09:48:24 |
|   95514 | 237699        | 1.000000 | auto |       1 |    7655 |         2763.0194 | 2010-07-22 09:48:24 |
|   95514 | 237658        | 2.000000 | auto |       1 |    7655 |         2763.0194 | 2010-07-22 09:48:24 |
+---------+---------------+----------+------+---------+---------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

The first three rows returned the first statement of the query in `UNION ALL`, while the fourth row returned the second statement. If we'll sum up the `qty` column, we can get the value of 5.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want `group by with rollup`:

```
SELECT i.id invn_id, 
        IF(ss.serial_id IS NOT NULL,ss.serial_id, NULL) serial_number, 
         -(SUM(IF(ss.serial_id IS NOT NULL, 1.000000, -(i.qty))) - -(i.qty)) qty, -- difference
        'auto' flag, i.sid site_id, i.prod_id, i.fifo_total_amount, i.trans_date
 FROM inventories i
 INNER JOIN prod p ON p.id = i.prod_id
 LEFT JOIN sale_products sp ON sp.inventory_id = i.id
 LEFT JOIN sale_serial ss ON ss.prod_id = i.prod_id AND ss.sale_id = sp.sale_id
 WHERE i.qty < 0
        AND ('2015-03-25 00:00:00' IS NULL OR i.trans_date >= '2015-03-25 00:00:00')
        AND ('2015-03-27 08:27:36' IS NULL OR i.trans_date <= '2015-03-27 08:27:36')
        AND p.name NOT IN ('Starting Balance' , 'Opening Balance', 'Equity')
        AND i.prod_id = 7655 AND (0 = 0 OR i.sid = 0)
 GROUP BY i.id WITH ROLLUP
 HAVING qty > 0 -- difference
```

However, I'm not 100% sure how this fits into the `SELECT` logic.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, however, I think I don't need `WITH ROLLUP` in this case. I already edited my question and explicated the output I wanna get.